# Is better to allocate/deallocate an IntPtr (AllocHGlobal) each time or preserve it?

Tags: c#, memory-management, intptr

I've a situation where I use AllocHGlobal (always of the same size) on a function which I use often (30 times each seconds probably), at the end of the function I call FreeHGlobal

Is better if I keep the part of memory allocated with AllocHGlobal and free it when the class Dispose or should I alloc/free each time I call the function?

I don't know how this memory behaves in c#, it's a "new world" for me

Comment: @Mitch: Heap global allocations are not subject to garbage collection, and are therefore "pinned" in the sense that nothing is going to be moving the allocation around in memory.  (Except maybe the kernel, but the VMM will take care of that transparently.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as long as:

- The amount of memory required is always less than or equal to the size of your allocation.  (You have already indicated that this is the case.)
- The method is not called from more than one thread at a time.
- The method is not re-entrant.
- You are careful to free the memory when it is no longer needed.  (In other words, if the pointer is saved on a non-static class field, the class should implement `IDisposable` and the `Dispose()` method should free the memory.  And, of course, the class consumers will have to call `Dispose()` or use a `using(){}` block.)

However, it's much more likely that the actual marshaling of the P/Invoke call is going to be the bottleneck.  Have you actually profiled the code yet, or are you micro-optimizing?

Comment: Actually the code works well, but I didn't test with high consumption jobs, I was just preventing the problem... I'll test.
**Edit:** damn, I'm wasting **a lot** (300MB) of memory, but I think the problem is due to Bitmap cloning, wait a second for another test

Comment: Solved, I did a lot of garbage in a part of the code. I optimized it and now doesn't waste a single byte (I'm always around 28 MB with a WinForm, I think it's good), had to preserve the AllocHGlobal by the way

Answer (score 2):

30 seconds is an eternity.  Much easier to put the FreeHGlobal in a finally block to ensure it's released.  Saves you from having to do to do the finalizer and IDisposable song and dance.  Well, the client's code.

Favoring the caching over the heap churn doesn't start to pay off until it gets in the millisecond range.

Comment: (Or *sub*-millisecond range.)

Comment: Did he say "30 seconds" or "30 times a second?" Even the latter is time enough to do quite a bit these days, but it does begin to justify optimization considerations that would be completely pointless in a 30-second regime.

Answer (score 1):

As with any performance question - write clean code first, measure and optimize what is needed.

If you are pretty sure that your object will not ever be used by multiple threads (thus making simultaneous calls to the function in question) it seems to fine to cache allocated memory.

If you decide to cache the unmanged block of memory relying on garbage collection will likley not be enough to free the memory early enough. Unmanged memory (AllocHGlobal) is not counted against CLR allocated memory thus potentially delaying garbage collection of your objects). You should implement and properlly use IDisposable on your objects.

Comment: Thanks, I think the code is already clean by the way (I write in such a clever way that my lib worked on the first try, without any bug... I'm really happy, first time it happens :P). Multiple threads problems... I should think about this